# Symfony error while doctrine:database:create

Tags: ubuntu, doctrine, symfony

I typed the following command to synchronize the database

```
php bin/console doctrine:database:create
```

But it returned me the following error message :

> PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\ClassNotFoundException: Attempted to load class "DOMDocument" from the global namespace.
>   Did you forget a "use" statement? in /opt/lampp/htdocs/linguavel/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Config/Util/XmlUtils.php:52
>   Stack trace:
>   0 /opt/lampp/htdocs/linguavel/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/DependencyInjection/Loader/XmlFileLoader.php(261): Symfony\Component\Config\Util\XmlUtils::loadFile('/opt/lampp/htdo...', Array)
>   1 /opt/lampp/htdocs/linguavel/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/DependencyInjection/Loader/XmlFileLoader.php(41): Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Loader\XmlFileLoader->parseFileToDOM('/opt/lampp/htdo...')
>   2 /opt/lampp/htdocs/linguavel/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Bundle/FrameworkBundle/DependencyInjection/FrameworkExtension.php(58): Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Loader\XmlFileLoader->load('web.xml')
>   3 /opt/lampp/htdocs/linguavel/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/DependencyInjection/Comp in /opt/lampp/htdocs/linguavel/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Config/Util/XmlUtils.php on line 52

Does someone know how to solve this issue ?
Thank's :)

EDIT

I ran composer install as Benjamin told me to do and it returned me this :

```
> Script Sensio\Bundle\DistributionBundle\Composer\ScriptHandler::clearCache handling the post-install-cmd event terminated with an exception


[RuntimeException]                                                  
An error occurred when executing the "'cache:clear --no-warmup'" c  
ommand:                                                             
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\Class  
NotFoundException: Attempted to load class "DOMDocument" from the   
global namespace.                                                   
Did you forget a "use" statement? in /opt/lampp/htdocs/linguavel/v  
endor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Config/Util/XmlUtils.p  
hp:52                                                               
Stack trace:                                                        
#0 /opt/lampp/htdocs/linguavel/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/  
Component/DependencyInjection/Loader/XmlFileLoader.php(261): Symfo  
ny\Component\Config\Util\XmlUtils::loadFile('/opt/lampp/htdo...',   
Array)                                                              
#1 /opt/lampp/htdocs/linguavel/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/  
Component/DependencyInjection/Loader/XmlFileLoader.php(41): Symfon  
y\Component\DependencyInjection\Loader\XmlFileLoader->parseFileToD  
OM('/opt/lampp/htdo...')                                            
#2 /opt/lampp/htdocs/linguavel/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/  
Bundle/FrameworkBundle/DependencyInjection/FrameworkExtension.php(  
58): Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Loader\XmlFileLoader->l  
oad('web.xml')                                                      
#3 /opt/lampp/htdocs/linguavel/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/  
Component/DependencyInjection/Comp in /opt/lampp/htdocs/linguavel/  
vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Config/Util/XmlUtils.  
php on line 52                                                      
.
```

NEW EDIT :

When I type composer update it returns me this :

To enable extensions, verify that they are enabled in those .ini files:
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/php.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/10-mysqlnd.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/10-opcache.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/10-pdo.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/15-xml.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-calendar.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-ctype.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-dom.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-exif.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-fileinfo.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-ftp.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-gettext.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-iconv.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-json.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-mcrypt.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-mysqli.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-pdo_mysql.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-phar.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-posix.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-readline.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-shmop.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-simplexml.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-sockets.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-sysvmsg.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-sysvsem.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-sysvshm.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-tokenizer.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-wddx.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-xmlreader.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-xmlwriter.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-xsl.ini
  You can also run `php --ini` inside terminal to see which files are used by PHP in CLI mode.

Comment: Can you run `composer install` and retry ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I finally managed to solve the problem by doing this :

```
$ sudo apt-get install php-curl
$ sudo apt-get install php-mbstring
$ sudo apt-get update
$ composer install
```

According to what I understood, this problem occurred because I have php7.0

In case you are using php7.0 and symfony 2 run the following command

`$sudo apt-get install php7.0-curl php7.0-mbstring php7.0-zip php7.0-xml`

After that run

`php app/check.php`

To see if there are any other missing requirements.

Comment: Hi FabulousCo. mbstring is a requirement. I found out you can look in the file `var/SymfonyRequirements.php` (but don't edit this file), to see what the `bin/symfony_requirements` is doing. I still highly recommend that you always run `php bin/symfony_requirements` to verify your install. Also, this will get updated per release.

Answer (score 5):

By the way, have you tried running:

```
php bin/symfony_requirements
```

to see what that show you?
You may be missing an installation requirement...

Answer (score 0):

You don't have the PHP `ext/dom` extension installed on your machine. On Ubuntu you need to run something like `sudo apt-get install php-xml`.

**EDIT**

It seems as if `ext/dom` is installed correctly. Please create a simple PHP file with

```
<?php
namespace Test;

$d = new \DOMDocument();
```

If that works there is something seriously messed up in your setup.

Comment: Check if the extension is available (which means activated in the configuration file) by looking at the output of `phpinfo()`.

Comment: I have to type phpinfo() in the terminal ?

Comment: No. Put `<?php phpinfo(); ?>` into a simple PHP file in your `web` folder and access it with your browser.

Comment: it returned version 5.6.23

Comment: You need to look for `dom` and if not found, check which config files (at the very beginning) are being used.

Comment: DOM/XML enabled
DOM/XML API Version 20031129
libxml Version 2.8.0
HTML Support enabled
XPath Support enabled
XPointer Support enabled
Schema Support enabled
RelaxNG Support enabled

Comment: Oh. I just realized that you're getting the error when running on CLI. Sorry for that. Try running `php -m` on the terminal and check for `dom`.

Comment: there is dom indeed :)

Comment: Which Symfony version did you install?

Comment: I got Symfony3 and I'm on ubuntu 16

Comment: It returned a blank page